# dexterity related items - browse for items has no content

Tags: plone, dexterity, z3c.form

I'm having an issue with the "browse for items" overlay for the default widget for z3c.relationfield, which I believe is using plone.formwidget.contenttree. I've created a custom field using this but get the same problem using the IRelatedItems behavior - the overlay has no browsable content. I am still able to use the autocomplete component of this widget, and can set relations programmatically with no problem, so I don't believe there is a problem with the intids utility. I've also tested on my local machine and on a dev server and everything works perfectly, just not in production (of course).

I apologize for the vague nature of this question, but I'm stumped. Are there any common pitfalls I could look for here? Any configuration step I might be overlooking?

Comment: I believe there was some issue with having imported a zexp file of a folder that had relations set into it. I would have thought these relations would be cleared on a zexp export, but perhaps not. I didn't delve further into this - I just recreated the content manually and it had no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Dexterity documentation and note the following:

- [Relation support no longer included by default](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.dexterity#relation-support-no-longer-included-by-default)
- [Content tree and Autocomplete widgets no longer included by default](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.dexterity#content-tree-and-autocomplete-widgets-no-longer-included-by-default)

So maybe you need to install the widget packages manually.